# Do I have to file ITR2 if I did not sell stocks in FY17-18?

Tags: stocks, income-tax, india, mutual-funds

I've a question related to filing ITR - whether I've to file ITR1 or ITR2. Below is my scenario.

I'm a salaried employee and I hold a Form-16 for FY1718. During FY1718, I bought few shares which I'm still holding and never performed *sell* transaction on any of them. Also, I've invested in MF targeted for one year which is yet to complete. Since I did not perform the *sell* operation either in stocks or in MF, shall I consider filing ITR1 instead of ITR2.

Please share your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can file ITR1. Only if you have capital gains or other items with different rate of tax, you are required to file ITR2

Answer (score 2):

In my case also, I have bought stocks in financial year ending March 2018.
In that financial year didnt sold any stocks. 
So, I was also having same confusion regarding filing ITR's.
I consulted a known CA, and told whole case.
He asked me to file ony ITR-1. 
I did filed. 
Income tax dept processed it and I got me refund back also.